# Working with html template tag and can't seem to display whole array of information

Tags: javascript, html, dictionary

This is my first time working with the html template tag. I don't know if I am doing it wrong but the output of the template is only showing the last item in the array. I've tried to loop through it and the foreach method but still only the last item shows. I know I am probably overriding the items as they are stacked on top of each other but I can't seem to figure it out Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
<div class="products-container">
                <template>
                    <div class="product">
                        <img class="img">
                        <h2 class="item-title"></h2>
                        <h3 class="price"></h3>
                    </div>
                </template>
            </div>

const template = document.querySelector('template').content
const copyTemplate = document.importNode(template, true)

let shoppingList = [];

async function getData(data) {


    const products = data.items.map(product => {
        
        copyTemplate.querySelector('.item-title').textContent = product.title;
        copyTemplate.querySelector('.price').textContent = product.price;
        copyTemplate.querySelector('.img').src = product.image;
    });


    document.querySelector('.products-container').appendChild(copyTemplate);
    shoppingList.push(products);
    return products
}
```

Comment: you have to append the item as you map through it.....bcz if you will continue to map through it you will reach the end of the array....so just add the  3rd last  line { document.querySelector('.products-container').appendChild(copyTemplate); } into the map function and it will work.

Comment: @KaranSingh Hi, that doesn't work. Now, it only returns the first item in the array

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had to put the template and the copytemplate within the map function for it to work.